# Cannot getBean after adding @Component above Class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I cannot get the bean by adding @Component on it.
I have created a class as below for getting bean in cases where instances are not injected by @autowired.

```
@Component
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware{
    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;
    

    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = context;
        
    }
}
```

Then I created a AppProperties class for reading the decrypt token from application.properties.

```
@Component
public class AppProperties {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    public String getTokenSecret() {
        return env.getProperty("tokenSecret");
    }
}
```

Then, I try to get the AppProperties instance as bean like this, which SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret() are used as parameter by manually inject in another method like this:

```
public class SecurityConstants {

    ...
    
    public static String getTokenSecret() {
        //Fail to get bean in this line
        AppProperties appProperties = (AppProperties)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("AppProperties"); 
        return appProperties.getTokenSecret();
    }

}
```

but fail with below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'AppProperties' available
```

After that, I add getAppProperties() with @Bean to make it register as a bean and it worked.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RegAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name="AppProperties")
    public AppProperties getAppProperties() {
        return new AppProperties();
        }
    
}
```

The question is:

1. Why SpringApplicationContext is run on application start and AppProperties does not?
2. Why cannot get AppProperties as bean? Isn't adding @Component above the class will make it a component scan target, thus being treated as a bean?
3. How adding getAppProperties() with @Bean making it different with adding @Component above the class?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `appProperties`. Default bean names tend to be camel cased.

Comment: @RobSpoor Thank you. It worked. But do you know why I have to add @ Component above SpringApplicationContext class to make the the setApplicationContext() run? Is it because SpringApplicationContext will be autowired to somewhere else?

Comment: In Spring, only beans are treated specially. Those are classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Configuration`, etc., or return values of methods annotated with `@Bean`.